# Copy field values in Acrobat using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

How can I copy the form field values from one set of fields to another using javascript.

The idea here is to have a 'use shipping/billing address' type of button that copies the user information from one block of fields to another identical set of fields.

Right now, I call an action upon click of a button to execute the following javascript:

```
this.field1.value = this.field2.value;
```

However that action yields an 'undefined' error in the debugger.

Comment: That looks right.  Can you paste more/all of the code so we can look for an inconsistency elsewhere?

Comment: That's all I've got. It just runs this code as an action when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For posterity, this is the solution to the problem:

```
getField("field2").value = getField("field1").valueAsString;
```

Also, note that `field2` is set to `field1` so the order is backwards.

Answer (score 5):

I used the following code to avoid overwriting the value in the second field if it has something in it already:

```
//Set the source and destination vars:
      var source = this.getField("Box1");
      var destination = this.getField("Box2");

//See if destination is empty and if so, insert source value
      if(destination.value==''||destination.value==null){destination.value=source.value}
```

I used it on "On Blur" of the source Field, but you could use a button with "Mouse Up" as the trigger. (I found the code on [this website](http://blogs.uoregon.edu/developments/2010/07/14/use-data-from-one-field-to-populate-other-fields-in-an-acrobat-fill-in-forms/). It includes more complicated options for populating multiple fields or even joining values from two source fields into one destination field.)